# IOS GAP Central does not discover Peripheral

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm currently working on a project, for which I need ti use BLE GAP, I have found a [tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/transferring_data_between_bluetooth_low_energy_devices) in the ios documentation and adapted the code for my needs.
The code does not throw any errors nor warnings, it runs smoothly but for some reason the discovery does not happen and it seems like the two devices would be miles apart
I tried everything but really cannot find the problem or even imagine what it could be since the code is almost identical to the original(which works.) It has to be something obvious I'm overlooking....

Peripheral log:

```
name[587:75475] Peripheral CBManager is powered on
```

Central log:

```
name[4803:2263279] Central CBManager is powered on
name[4803:2263279] Found connected Peripherals with transfer service: (
)
```

Peripheral Code:

https://pastebin.com/WuKymHAS

Central Code:

https://pastebin.com/ijjHk4cG
I've changed the UUID, but I've also tried it with the ones from the tutorial. The classes are initiated with the loadBLE methods.

I would be very thankful I someone could give me a hint, why they don't "see" each other
greets!

Comment: You aren't calling advertising? During scanning, remove the scan for specific service, add it later when it works...

Comment: You've commented out the `startAdvertising`, and you didn't include any logging around it, so it's not clear if you're calling it (or if you're calling it too soon, before power-on). When you use precisely the sample code from Apple, does that work? Note that a contact-tracking app that runs in the background is incredibly difficult to build in iOS if that's what you're trying to do (and nightmarish to build cross-platform). I encourage folks to work on hard problems, so feel free, but it's one of the most difficult BLE problems I've worked on, and there's no simple "just works" solution.

Comment: (Note that if this really is intended as a contact tracking app, please make sure it's reviewed by a security assessor before shipping it to anyone. Dealing with privacy concerns in this kind of app is very challenging, and if it were deployed sufficiently to be a useful tracking app, it could do substantial harm if its security is not designed correctly from the start.)

Comment: @RobNapie Ohh, ok. So I just called the `advertising` method too early. So if I call it later, it will probably work....(I will try that tomorrow). Thx! The app is just a hobby project and I did in no way intend to build a serious solution to a world wide problem.(but I do like to work on hard projects). However I'm as good as done with the IOS version, you can find my project on GitHub (name: covidIsolate) if you are interested in my amateur doings :D.

Comment: @Larme thanks, I was in a rapid hole. I commented it out because it triggered an error. I didn't know thta I just called it too early and thought the delegate would do that by his own.

Comment: You should be getting an error like "API Misuse, can only accept commands while in the powered on state" or something like that. You can't start interacting with Core Bluetooth until it tells you it's powered on (that message tells you it's powered on *for your app*; this is not precisely the same thing as "powered on in the hardware").

Comment: Looking over the code, it's fine to play with and it'll kind of work as long as there aren't very many devices running the app that you've ever seen (and definitely not too many nearby). It's has the typical O(n^2) connection design that would overwhelm the local Bluetooth network (and would quickly run into resources limits on the phone as well). But it's perfectly fine as a toy app to learn your way around BLE. Best of luck!

Comment: I got exactly that error.... .What kind of database structure would you think of?(if coreData is too volatile, because I thought that it had a light SQL backend). And what would be an approach to handle high bluetooth loads(workaround to not overwhelm the bl network)? thanks and greets